# Приложении закрывается с ошибкой при обращении к несуществующему серверу

Tags: android

Не так давно погружаюсь в Андроид-разработку. Решил написать простенькое приложение исключительно для отработки навыков и знакомства с библиотеками. Для сетевого взаимодействия решил использовать фреймворк Ktor, на котором написал простенький сервер.
Сервер при GET запросе к нему отвечает текстом. Всё максимально просто.
В приложении была реализована следующая логика:

1. Приложение отправляет GET запрос на сервер
2. Ответ сравнивается с ожидаемым
3. При соответствии переход на активити 1, при несоответствии на активити 2.
   Тут тоже всё максимально просто.

Удалось добиться рабочего кода:

```
private fun sentToken() { // Функция для реализации сетевого взаимодействия
        val client = HttpClient()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response: String = client.get(BASE_URL)
            client.close()

            // Функция, реализующая переход на активити 1 или 2
            serverResponse(response)
        }
    }
```

В чём же проблема?

Суть в том, что всё хорошо работает при активном сервере. Но стоит завершить его работу или отключить wifi, приложение вылетает с ошибкой.
Как задать логику в случае полного отсутствия ответа сервера?

Comment: В try catch оберните, корутины не умеют в обработку ошибок прямо вот так, поэтому и падение

Comment: try catch помогло, всё заработало.
Спасибо